# Python Thread() deleting the newline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, newline

I came across a peculiar bug in my program. The general idea behind the code is that at first an array of 5 lists gets created (called lists_of_nums). Each list consists of 100 numbers within the range of 1 and 10 000. The program then runs 5 threads. Each one finds the mean value of a single list, as well as prints the time taken to do it.

You'll notice that at the end of the print() statement in the threading_function() there is a single newline. Right where it says "seconds.\n".

The problem is, if I put the 't.join()' in a separate 'for' loop (very bottom of my code), in order to run threads simultaneously, that newline sometimes gets removed (apparently). It only works 100% of the time if I run the threads separately, one by one.

I was hoping someone could please help me understand how to run the threads simultaneously and still have that newline be reliable.

Let me demonstrate what I mean with an example of the code and its incorrect output (that only occurs some of the time):

```
lists_of_nums = []

def create_set():    # Function for creating a list of random integers and appending them to the lists_of_nums array.

    random_nums = []

    for _ in range(100):

        random_nums.append(randint(1, 10000))

    lists_of_nums.append(random_nums)

for _ in range(5):    # Five of these lists get appended to the array, by using the create_set() function.
    create_set()


def threading_function(list_index):    # Function responsible for finding the mean value of a given list as well as the time taken to do it.

    start = timeit.default_timer()

    mean_value = mean(lists_of_nums[list_index])

    end = timeit.default_timer() - start

    print(
        "The mean value of the list number " + str(list_index + 1) + " is " + str(mean_value) +
        "\nThe time taken to find it was " + str(end) + " seconds.\n" # The abovementioned newline.
        )

threads = []

for i in range(len(lists_of_nums)):

    t = Thread(target = threading_function, args = [i])
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:    # If t.join() remains in a separate 'for' loop than the Thread() class, the newline occasionally disappears.
    t.join()
```

Incorrect output, where the newline has seemingly disappeared between the print statement 3 and 4:

```
The mean value of the list number 1 is 5270.34
The time taken to find it was 0.00012170000000000236 seconds.

The mean value of the list number 2 is 4768.17
The time taken to find it was 9.239999999999943e-05 seconds.

The mean value of the list number 3 is 4766.67
The time taken to find it was 8.369999999999905e-05 seconds.
The mean value of the list number 4 is 4969.7
The time taken to find it was 9.880000000000305e-05 seconds.


The mean value of the list number 5 is 4686.21
The time taken to find it was 9.25000000000023e-05 seconds.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline is being printed.  Note that you have an extra line between statements 4 and 5.  You've probably got a race condition between your threads.  Try protecting the `print` function with a lock.  I.e.,

```
printLock = threading.Lock() # global variable
```

And then

```
# inside threading_function
with printLock:
    print(
        "The mean value of the list number " + str(list_index + 1) + " is " + str(mean_value) +
        "\nThe time taken to find it was " + str(end) + " seconds.\n" # The abovementioned newline.
        )
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! I wasn't even aware of the concept of data races. My code works as intended now :)

Answer (score 2):

The newline in your string is intact. `print` by default adds a newline afterwards. It does this in a separate write. The two writes (the original string and the newline) from different threads can be interleaved, hence you also sometimes see a double blank line. You'll see similar weird effects if you remove the newline from your string.

One solution is to end your string in two newlines and stop `print` from adding its own, i.e. `print("....\n\n", end="")`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure fusing the newline into the string isn't actually a safe approach, even assuming the current CPython implementation. Interruptions might be less likely, but I'm pretty sure they're still possible.